# Get Value From User

Tags: php, iframe

This is my code

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=[VIDEO ID PASTE HERE]" width="1280" height="720" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I want the `VIDEO ID` to come from user input. This is my form code:

```
<form method="get">
<input type = "text" name= "videoid">
<input type="button">
</form>
```

What should I do in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=<?php echo $_GET['videoid'] ?>" width="1280" height="720" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

the whole page code will be like this ...

```
<form action="" method="get">
<input type = "text" name= "videoid">
<input type="submit" value='Show video' name='submit'>
</form> 

<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['videoid'])) {
        $id = $_GET['videoid'];
        ?>

        <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=<?php echo $id; ?>" width="1280" height="720" frameborder="0"></iframe>

        <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Ur Answer Is Helpful but How can i Show in After I Click on Submit

Answer (score 0):

First your HTML should be a little more thorough with an action set, depending on the page

```
<form action="" method="get">
<input type="text" name="videoid">
<input type="button">
</form>
```

And your iFrame

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=<?php echo filter_var($_GET['videoid'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); ?>" width="1280" height="720" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: how can i use Iframe Tag on a Function

Comment: What do you mean on a function?